# Xpath behaving differently on Selectorshub and on live code. (C# Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to get a list of rows in a table as IWebelEments to parse their contents for testing purposes

I'm trying using the following piece of code (the variable has been declared globally for the class as public IList IWebElement Rows):

```
public class SearchResults : Widget
{
    public IList<IWebElement> rows;

    public SearchResults(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        rows = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='tblResults']//tr"));
```

The strange thing is that when testing it on selectorshub this Xpath returns the correct value:

[image: Result from Selectorshub]

But when debugging the way it's behaving it appears to be gathering 11 instances of the first row in the IList. Which is strange, since it shows that it's adding the correct number of members to the list, but for some reasons it only gets eleven instances of the first row in the table body.

[image: TC debuggin]
I have tried multiple versions of the Xpath. Making the variable local instead of global, and testing it live con the browser and with selectorshub. I wasn't able to get anything close to the wanted result.

UPDATE: I have also tried making single element Xpaths  using an iterator to build an Xpath for each row and i'm still finding the same problem, for some reason each of these Xpaths catch the same element on the script while on the browser they catch the proper elements:

```
//table[@id='tblResults']//tbody//tr[1]
//table[@id='tblResults']//tbody//tr[2]
//table[@id='tblResults']//tbody//tr[3]
//table[@id='tblResults']//tbody//tr[4]
//table[@id='tblResults']//tbody//tr[5]
```

and so on...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a relevant amount of the HTML you are testing. Is JavaScript doing something on the page to change the elements? This might be an issue of timing. When you run automation code, it can execute very quickly compared to a human doing something. Race conditions are an ever present challenge with Selenium.